# How to uninstall app via source command?

Tags: gnome, scripts, nautilus, uninstall, source

I have installed a `nautilus` `script` called `Hash Checker` v4.0.8 (https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1007703/), but somehow it is not shown in the right-click menu anyway. It was placed on my Desktop and I can run it from there and I can't place it anyway else.

I have installed it by running the Setup file with the `source` command:

```
source Setup
```

Now I would like to uninstall it. Whats the way to go here?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Installation and usage

Installation is done by launching `Setup` script.

This program looks slightly old, so I tested it first on old GNOME 2 system.

I tested your script on pretty old Ubuntu 11.04 with cool and nice Nautilus 2.32. It works here as expected. It creates icon on desktop (on click it opens file selection dialog) and drop-down menu in Nautilus (*Scripts->Check hash*).
After object selection it asks for checksum methods

[image: Hash Checker window 1]

and shows calculated checksums

[image: Hash Checker window 2]

---

What we have on modern Ubuntu:

- on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS it works from desktop-shortcut, but does not work from Nautilus drop-down (there is no *Scripts* section here in Nautilus).
  **But you can make it working by copying script file to the GNOME3 location:**

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts 
  cp ~/.HashCheck/Check\ hash ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
  ```
- on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS with MATE DE and Caja file-manager it fully works out-the-box.

## Uninstallation

According to its readme file it can be removed by running the same `Setup` file.

[image: Hash Checker uninstall]

If it does not work you can remove it manually:

```
rm -rf /home/$USER/.HashCheck
rm "/home/$USER/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/Check hash"
rm /home/$USER/Desktop/HashChecker.desktop
```